# TFS Java API - Authentication Issue

Tags: tfs

I am trying to authentication through Java SDK (TFS-SDK-12.0.1) but not able to get through. Any help will be highly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
    URI serverURI = new URI("http://localhost:8080/tfs");///DefaultCollection");

    //Credentials credentials = new DefaultNTCredentials();
    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "GWt@try");

    System.out.println("Trying to connect..");
    SnippetsSamplesConnectionAdvisor connectionAdvisor = new SnippetsSamplesConnectionAdvisor(null);
    //TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(serverURI, credentials);
    TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(URIUtils.newURI("http://localhost:8080/tfs"), credentials, connectionAdvisor);
    WorkItemClient workItemClient = tpc.getWorkItemClient();
```

You can ignore the commented lines, its there just to tell you guyz that I've tried those options as well. I am getting the following exception when I try UsernamePasswordCredentials:

```
Trying to connect..
WARN  [main] TFSTeamProjectCollection - Error getting data provider
com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.auth.AuthenticationSecurityException: Basic credentials are only supported over HTTPS secured connections.
```

And the following when I use DefaultNTCredentials:

```
Trying to connect..
WARN  [main] HttpMethodDirector - Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {basic=Basic realm="localhost"}
WARN  [main] TFSTeamProjectCollection - Error getting data provider
com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TFSUnauthorizedException: Access denied connecting to TFS server http://localhost:8080/ (authenticating as White-Rabbit\Sumukh)
```

My end goal is to connect to TFS Server and update/create work items. Any pointers? Please help.

I can connect to TFS through UI, please click on the following link to see the screenshot: http://grab.by/xnlU

Comment: Guyz, anyone had a chance to look at this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you actually specify the connection?  It's very odd that this would fall back to Basic credentials...  Can you actually connect with Team Explorer Everywhere clients?

Comment: Yes, I am having no issues with team explorer.

Comment: Great to hear.  Can you post a screenshot of the connect dialog?

Comment: Hi Edward,  thanks for your response. Please click on the following link to see the screenshot: http://grab.by/xnlU

Comment: I have been trying to find methods in API which can provide NTLM authentication. For example: 

com.microsoft.tfs.core.httpclient.auth.NTLMSecurityProvider

But not sure how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Administration.
Under settings Tab,
Allow *Alternate authentication credentials*